# Apache Flink: Exception when using JDBCOutputFormat

Tags: apache-flink

I implemented a Flink programm and tried to store the result `DataSet` into relational database. I did the following command:

```
data.output(JDBCOutputFormat.buildJDBCOutputFormat()
                    .setDBUrl(dbURL)
                    .setDrivername(drivername)
                    .setUsername(username)
                    .setPassword(password)
                    .finish()
                    );
```

`dbUrl`,`drivername`, `username` and `password` are separately stored in a String.

I get the following error:

```
The method output(OutputFormat<Tuple8<String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String>>) 
in the type DataSet<Tuple8<String,String,String,String,String,String,String,String>> 
is not applicable for the arguments (JDBCOutputFormat)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide us with the full exception. What does the DataSet data contain? The JDBCOutputFormat can only be used if the DataSet contains Rows (a specific Flink type).

Comment: data set looks like:

`DataSet<Tuple8<String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String>> data=env.readCsvFile("D:\\WorkDocument\\Dummy_data\\data")
          .fieldDelimiter("|")
          .types(String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class);
  `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, it looks like your DataSet is not of the type Row (org.apache.flink.types.Row). Convert it to Row type and then call the output function.

Example code to convert variable 'value' of Tuple2 type to Row.

```
Row obj = new Row(2);
obj.setField(0,value.f0);
obj.setField(1,value.f1);
```

Since your DataSet contains elements of Tuple8 type, your Row should be of size 8 (Row(8)). You can use a map function to transform each element from Tuple8 to Row.

Comment: How to convert a dataset<Row> from a dataset<Tuple>